# Horizontal Enumerate

Tags: lists, enumitem

I am currently working on a template for a document I am preparing. Here are some of the paramaters I am working with:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Enumerate Environment
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{enumitem}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newlist{enumexample}{enumerate}{3}%
\setlist[enumexample]{label=\arabic*, font=\bfseries, align=left, leftmargin=*, labelsep=1em, labelwidth=*,itemsep=2.5ex}
\setlist[enumexample,2]{label=\Alph*, font=\bfseries, leftmargin=*,itemsep=1ex}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumexample}
        \item Sample
            \begin{enumexample}
            \item 1.2 N
            \item 1.3 N
            \item 1.4 N
            \item 1.5 N
            \end{enumexample}
        \item Sample
            \begin{enumexample}
            \item Sample
            \item Sample
            \item Sample
            \item Sample
            \end{enumexample}
        \item Sample
            \begin{enumexample}
            \item 1.2 cm
            \item 1.3 cm
            \item 1.4 cm
            \item 1.5 cm
            \end{enumexample}
        \item Sample
            \begin{enumexample}
            \item Sample
            \item Sample
            \item Sample
            \item Sample
            \end{enumexample}
        \item Sample
            \begin{enumexample}
            \item Sample
            \item Sample
            \item Sample
            \item Sample
            \end{enumexample}
    \end{enumexample}
\end{document}
```

This produces the vertical enumeration correctly. What I am trying to figure out is how to enumerate horizontally as shown below. This will be used for short text input and the spacing should be consistent throughout the document; meaning that if I have two consecutive questions with varied small text input, the letter options should still be aligned.

[image]

From the MWE, the usage entails to put short text input in horizontal listing; that is, the ones with the measurements should be in horizontal mode.

[image]
[image]

Comment: `tasks` maybe? Or fake it with `tabular`? Why are you posting a snippet rather than a proper minimal example?

Comment: @cfr Let me update with the MWE. Note there are many instances of the usage of the enumerate.

Comment: Your MWE should demonstrate the issue. So you want probably two horizontal lists with different length items, I expect.

Comment: @cfr I updated the questions with more visuals. I am still working on my end to get it. I know `enumitem` has `inline` but not sure if it can calculate the item width on the fly to have the enumeration work as shown above. I will research about `tasks`.

Comment: You can't use `enumitem`'s `inline` for this. It is designed to typeset items in running text, as part of a paragraph. `tasks` seems pretty simple, though. I've never used it before - just knew it could do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tasks` for this.

[image: horizontal lists with tasks]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}
\newlist{enumexample}{enumerate}{3}%
\setlist[enumexample]{label=\arabic*, font=\bfseries, align=left, leftmargin=*, labelsep=1em, labelwidth=*,itemsep=2.5ex}
\setlist[enumexample,2]{label=\Alph*, font=\bfseries, leftmargin=*,itemsep=1ex}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumexample}
  \item Sample
  \begin{tasks}[label=\Alph*](4)
    \task 1.2 N
    \task 1.3 N
    \task 1.4 N
    \task 1.5 N
  \end{tasks}
  \item Sample
  \begin{enumexample}
    \item Sample
    \item Sample
    \item Sample
    \item Sample
  \end{enumexample}
  \item Sample
  \begin{tasks}[label=\Alph*](4)
    \task 1.2 cm
    \task 1.3 cm
    \task 1.4 cm
    \task 1.5 cm
  \end{tasks}
  \item Sample
  \begin{enumexample}
    \item Sample
    \item Sample
    \item Sample
    \item Sample
  \end{enumexample}
  \item Sample
  \begin{enumexample}
    \item Sample
    \item Sample
    \item Sample
    \item Sample
  \end{enumexample}
\end{enumexample}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this but not sure: `[label=\Alph*, label-format=\bfseries,item-indent=1.5em](4)`

Comment: @azetina You can configure it, I think. Like I said, this is the first time I've ever used this, but the documentation seems good. There's a picture on page 9 similar to the diagrams `enumitem` uses. You might want to use `debug` to see what is going on.

Comment: @azetina However, I could wish the author had chosen something other than yellow on white for keys!

Comment: @azetina I think you either need to figure out the results of `enumitem`'s calculations for level 2 or you need to set something explicit there which you can match for `tasks`. Otherwise, it is just guessing.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the support! I will be working on it and will update the MWE with my end result.

Comment: @azetina It's best not to edit your final solution into the question or the Q&A format no longer makes sense ;). You can also post another answer and note you modified mine or whatever.